# What is the shortcut to copy the link location in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, webpage

Is there any way to use shortcuts to copy the link location in Firefox?

[image]

For example take the above Google webpage in Firefox -- here `"tamil"` was the text with hyperlink. Usually we used to press either copy by right click --> copy link location and paste the hyperlink over there; I don't wish to copy the hyperlink by right click and would rather use shortcuts.

I am using Windows XP service pack with Firefox version 23.1

Comment: What do you mean by link location? You mean the URL of the page you are currently looking at?

Comment: @slhck added image for better clarification,while looking at webpage there might be n number of hyperlinks while copy pasting it genreally doesnt give urls instead it will paste it as plain text

Comment: Thanks, I understand which action you mean, but what do you want it to do? When you copy the link location, it **will already be a URL** – in plain text, for example `http://example.com`. What kind of shortcut are you thinking? A keyboard shortcut? How would it know which URL you want to copy?

Comment: @slhck now clarified and updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that is not exactly what you are looking for but you can **Ctrl + left click** the link to open it in a new tab.

You can then **Ctrl + Tab** to show the new tab

I don't think there is any *keyboard + mouse* shortcuts for copying the link location

Comment: To open in a new tab one can also use just middle-click. But `there is no keyboard + mouse shortcuts for copying the link location` is false.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to copy the link location of a hyperlink?

Try this:

- Hover over the item,
- Right Click + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Paste the link wherever you want.
  The link will be on your clipboard.

Comment: This method doesn't work on sites such as https://music.youtube.com/ which disable the browser context menu.

Comment: @user598527 in Firefox you can hold "Shift" key while using right click to override any page specific context menu.

Answer (score 3):

To copy the link location of a hyperlink (on Firefox), do `Right Click + L`
(Works as of 11 May, 2021, 07:17 GMT)

Comment: For me `l + Right-click` works on Firefox. `Right-click + l` doesn't do anything (it just opens the context menu as if I just pressed `Right-click`).

Comment: That seems to open option to create a new bookmark. `Right-click+A` copies the link to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

I've wanted this feature for years. As far as I know, there isn't a built-in way to do this, nor has anybody made an addon. I got sick of waiting, so I forked a similar addon and modified it for this purpose: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-link-with-click/

Here's a screenshot of the settings:

[image]

It's open source. Here's the repository: https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/copy-link-with-click

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the Link Hints plugin a try:

> What is Link Hints?
>
> Link Hints is a browser extension that complements the built-in keyboard >shortcuts with ones for clicking.

https://lydell.github.io/LinkHints/tutorial.html#step-7